# How to split country code and phone number in java script

Tags: javascript

I have a number example this : - +91xxxxxxxxxx i want to split country code and mobile number.

The number is stored in a variable.  and i want to split the number from end. because i am only using those country whose phone number is 10 digit long. So i can count from last and split after 10 numbers. But how to do this. I don't know.

please help.

Comment: What you have tried??? Not a single line?

Comment: if your country code is +NN then just get the 3 fits characters from your phone number and keep the last numbers as "phone" ^^

Comment: @Julo0sS but country code will be different for other countries.

Comment: @Manwal i was using split. but i am confuse how to split it. because i want to start from end of the string. So that i can count the numbers and split the string.

Comment: With out all the country code for reference its not possible

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```js
const phoneNumber = '+91xxxxxxxxxx';
const countryCodeLength = phoneNumber.length - 10;

const components = {
    IDDCC: phoneNumber.substr(0, countryCodeLength), 
    NN: phoneNumber.substr(countryCodeLength, phoneNumber.length)
};
    
console.log(components);
```

Comment: That is not consistent. Better to use a library that knows the country codes.

Answer (score 0):

Country may have variable length code. So best possible solution would be start from back as of now we know length of mobile number is 10. once you take those 10 digits, Then you can parse country code accordingly.

Comment: yeah @Mathusuthanan I want to start from last. but can to tell how to do this ?

Comment: @RajeshKumar the gave you logic, are you expecting the code also?

Comment: I already know the logic bro.

Comment: @RajeshKumar did you try that?

Comment: @Muthusuthanan "now we know length of mobile number is 10" are you sure this statement is true in all countries.

Comment: I am not using all countries.. I am just using those countries whose mobile number contents 10 numbers

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam No,the mobile numbers length is differ accordingly to the countries,For that at the time of selecting the country load the country code in separate textbox dynamically and get the mobile number in a seperate textbox.so that you can easily handle this scenario.